Compositing with Geonodes not applied, is it possible?
I have a plane with a GeoNode setup that includes Cones on a heart-shaped plane.
My question is, in the compositing, I would like to change the color/Glare of the plane. But nothing seems to be happening, it's only affecting the cones.
I haven't applied the GeoNode because I want to work as flexible as possible. My question is if it's possbile to seperate the heart and cones to change color/glare with still having the GeoNode not applied.
The file: 


Compositing is performed on the image level, unless you have manually setup render layers, cryptomates, or separate passes it doesn't have the ability to distinguish between objects. If compositing has no visible effect then that is probably because the effect is too soft or something in the material is reducing the visibility, like say strong emission or very saturated colors

Does Cryptomates, seperate passes or render layers work with GeoNodes that arent applied?

Depends, Cryptomate might, but in your case it may not be adequate because you have a large object that "touches" many others, not sure how well it will behave. Render layers require different objects, but you may be able to separate a live instanced copy of your heart without breaking their link. Object Index Passes work on object level, so again if you separate a copy of your heard it may work.
